# Redirect subdomain and folder by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect
`it.example.com/it` to `https://example.com/it` in .htaccess

How would I do it?
I used this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^it.example.com/it
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/it/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it didn't work.

[image]

I use another .htaccess file in it directory. its content is

```
  RewriteBase /it/
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTTP_HOST` only matches host/domain name. It doesn't match URI.

You may use:

```sh
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^it\.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^it(?:/|$) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE.NC]
```

Comment: Thanks. My main domain didn't  work by this code. I have another domains similar mechnical.exaxmple.com and chemical.example.com and I don't want this code change them.

Comment: Just make sure this is your topmost rule in root .htaccess of `it.example.com` subdomain

Comment: It appears you don't have right SSL cert for `it.example.com`. Can you test by entering `http://it.example.com/it` in browser

Comment: http://it.example.com/it/ and it.example.com/it/ did not work. These domain show Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead message

Comment: That warning means you're requesting `https://` site not `http://`. Is your sire redirecting from `http->https`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226910/discussion-between-biodiversity-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to match URI in host variable, you need to remove your uri part from it. Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^it\.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```